# hash_value function in C++11

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

The Boost library provides a convenience function `hash_value` which basically just called:

```
return hash<T>()(key);
```

As far as I can see, C++11 included `std::hash` which is pretty similar to `boost::hash`, but did not include `std::hash_value`.  This requires application code to create a `hash` object and call it's `operator()` instead of just calling a convenient function.  Is there some reason that `std::hash_value` was not standardized?

Comment: At first glance `hash_value` looks like it should be a type. The naming convention for such functions would produce `make_hash`. In general I think functions names should be verbs.

Comment: That's true: `make_hash` would be acceptable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary use of the `std::hash<T>` function is the object used to obtain a hash value from a key in the `std::unordered_*` group of containers. These will always contain and use a corresponding object, possibly, using the empty base optimization to avoid it taking any memory. In any case, whenever the `std::hash<T>` type is used, an object is actually around.

Although the function object can be used stand-alone, it is probably rare. Also, for other, similar existing function objects there are no corresponding convenience calling functions: although most of them are wrappers for operators, especially `std::less<void*>` could be interesting to call stand-alone as you can't use `ptr1 < ptr2` (at least, it couldn't be used in C++03 if `ptr1` and `ptr2` were not part of the same array object). That is, there was no suitable precedence.

Finally, I would guess that the convenience function was simply not part of the proposal: if it isn't proposed and there isn't a really good case to have, nothing will be included into the C++ standard. From the looks of it [n1456](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html) seems to be, at least, one revision of the "hash table" proposal and it doesn't include a trace of `std::hash_value<T>()`.

Comment: Many functors can potentially be stateful. Even a hash could have `const` but nevertheless runtime configuration state. `std::less<T*>` implements the ordering over pointers from different allocation blocks disallowed for native `<` in C++03 and C++11 alike, but there is never an ordering of `void*` values except as an optional extension.